# How to solve Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException error in API connection? [Xamarin]

Tags: postgresql, api, xamarin

I had created an API and a Xamarin apps to consume the API. So I used "edge://inspect/#devices" to do port forwarding. I am able to connect the API in my Mobile physical device, but when I debug the application, it shown me this error

> Javax.Net.Ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> 'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found.'

and I can't run it. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Trust+anchor+for+certification+path+not+found+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason this is a Xamarin question and the answer is in Java so it is not 1:1. Most people are able to handle it but if someone can't it is legitimate to ask.

Comment: @IvanIčin it's ok, I got the solution. No worry, thank you :)